# proc tabulate remove default borders and color

Tags: sas

I'm trying to generate a simple Proc Tabulate output. I don't want the default borders and coloring in the cells.

```
proc format;
PICTURE PCTF (ROUND) OTHER='009.9%';
run;

PROC TABULATE DATA = X017;
CLASS EDUC 
      AREA
      AGE 
      SEX 
      CENRACE 
      POVERTY 
      EDUC 
      INSURE 
      HEALTH
      Q21 / style=[background=lightgreen];

TABLE AREA    * (ROWPCTN*f=PCTF.)
      AGE     * (ROWPCTN*f=PCTF.) 
      SEX     * (ROWPCTN*f=PCTF.)
      CENRACE * (ROWPCTN*f=PCTF.)
      POVERTY * (ROWPCTN*f=PCTF.)
      EDUC    * (ROWPCTN*f=PCTF.)
      INSURE  * (ROWPCTN*f=PCTF.) 
      HEALTH  * (ROWPCTN*f=PCTF.) , Q21 / BOX = "Question 21" ;
RUN;
```

[example of current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCJMi.png)

[example of desired table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmokw.png)

Comment: I have a custom style here that may get you relatively close, and you can modify as needed. https://gist.github.com/statgeek/9845cc3d26e4c35e01a2

Answer (score 1):

SAS has a variety of [pre-defined ODS styles](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_odsgraph_sect016.htm). Try using style `JOURNAL1A.` It appears to be what you are looking for. Check out this example. Note the `path` statement was only included because I have write access issues in the default location. This changes the path to WORK.

```
ods html path="%sysfunc(getoption(work) )" style=JOURNAL1A;

proc tabulate data=sashelp.cars;
    class origin type;
    table origin, type;
run;
```

[image: JOURNAL1A]